# Find the limit : $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigg(1-\frac{|x|}{\pi}\Bigg)^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to find the following

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \Bigg(1-\frac{|x|}{\pi}\Bigg)^n$$

Any hints please ?

Comment: Could "$\pi$" here be a typo for $n$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Notice that if $a$ is independent of $n$, then  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a^n= \begin{cases} 0 , & -1 < a < 1 \\
1, & a=1\\
\text{diverges,} & \text{Otherwise}\end{cases}$$

In the event that $\pi$ is a typo and it is suppose to be $n$, then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1-\frac{|x|}{n}\right)^n=\exp(-|x|)$$

Comment: $π$ is not a typo